# probability question find how many buses

Tags: probability

i need a bus to run so it gives me a 1/2 chance of getting to point B faster than walking. The distance from point A to B is 1.5 miles. the speed of the bus is 25mph and the walking speed is 4mph

takes .375 hours to get by walking
takes takes .06 hours to get by taking bus
time difference is .3150 hours

The answer is 1.59 bus per hour but I am not sure how to get to this answer.....any help is appreciated!

Comment: isn't that the same question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480759/probability-question-bus-frequency

Comment: I thought when I answered your previous question that it was from a later part of a probability course. So I will modify by previous overly fancy answer.